# Multiple functions on form submit jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, analytics

I have to call two functions on form submit but i want to make sure that that second      function  is executed only after the first function is executed.
 I do not have control over the first function, so i cannot edit it at all.

```
function a(et){
   //function a script
}

 function b(evt){

 //function b script
}

from function b is there a way that i can check if function a was completed or executed fully.
```

Comment: So function a is asynchronous?

Comment: you can have a global variable and set it's value to some constant value in function a..and then check that value before calling function b

Comment: look at this, this may help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1370766/how-to-detect-when-one-function-is-complete-from-another-function

Comment: yes function a is asynchronous

Comment: What does function `a` do?

Comment: once the form is submitted, function a() displays the result. it is basically a store Locator page. once the form is submitted, it displays the number of stores found.

Comment: Have "b" check to see if the number of stores is visible...

Comment: Mathew, that is how i checked and is working as expected, thanks

Answer (score 1):

if you have *no access to `a` at all* then you can't do what you want to do here. No way: JS creates a call object when a function is called, and auto-GC's it when the call is complete. Sadly, the actual mem-management is off limits, so you can't check that. other trickery involves your meddling with the code of function `a`, which you say you cant get at... so no, you can't do this.

Sorry for that, but it's as the FAQ says: you might not always get the answer you're hoping for, but that doesn't mean the answer you don't like isn't true... :-P

---

There is, however, a little bit of hope for you: if both function `a` and `b` are callbacks or handlers of a submit event, you *could* look into ways of queueing those calls. Given the jQuery tag [`.queue()` suggests itself](http://api.jquery.com/queue/)

Answer (score 0):

According to [Eli Grey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/78436/eli-grey) you can tested like this:

```
function foo() {
  foo.complete = false;
  // your code here
  foo.complete = true;
}
foo.complete = false;

if (foo.complete) { // foo execution complete
  // your code here
}
```

Comment: the problem is i cannot update function foo(), so how do i add foo.complete=?  inside function foo()  :(

Comment: Well JavaScript has a single execution flow, so when a function it is call it will execute, so what you can do it is just put some events call, such as setInterval, if this bool becomes true, them the first function it is done so will be the green line to execute the next function

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can, there is a lot of ways to do that, but here is a simple way to make it.
You can use persistent object [localStorage](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2009/06/localstorage/).
You can use session object [sessionStorage](https://code.google.com/p/sessionstorage/).

```
function a(evt){
   // Asynchronous function
   // ... your code here
   // before finish function create the persistent object
   localStorage.setItem('myObject', 'done');
   return;
}

function b(evt){
   // Checks if a() function was completed
   var _done = localStorage.getItem('myObject');
   if(_done && _done == 'done') {
     // your code here: the a() function was completed
     localStorage.removeItem('myObject');
   }
}
```

Comment: OP can't do this: he hasn't got access to function `a`. Also `localStorage` isn't very X-browser friendly (older browsers don't support it)

Comment: You can use the [jQuery.data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/) function to add custom data to your dom objects.  
Implementation is similar as the sample above, you can add data to your dom object like this: 
`$("#div-response").data("myObject", "done");` 
To delete data you can use [jQuery.removeData()](http://api.jquery.com/removeData/) like this: 
`$("#div-response").removeData("myObject");`

Comment: Why use jQuery, why not simply `document.getElementById('div-response').setAttribute('data-myObject', 'done');`? Honestly, [there's nothing jQ does, that can't be done in vanilla JS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16472714/what-features-does-jquery-provide-that-arent-available-natively-in-the-browsers)

Comment: Thanks for your appreciation @EliasVanOotegem. I proposed jQuery because the question has jquery as tag. :)